# Bash 'Process substitution' - what is going on here?

Tags: bash, fifo

I am using process substitution to create a shorthand inline XSL function that I have written...

```
function _quickxsl() {
    if [[ $1 == "head" ]] ; then
        cat <<'HEAD'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
    <!ENTITY apos "&#39;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    xmlns:kcc="http://www.adp.com/kcc"
    extension-element-prefixes="func kcc">
HEAD
    else
        cat <<'FOOT'
</xsl:stylesheet>
FOOT
    fi
}

function quickxsl() {
    {
        _quickxsl head && cat && _quickxsl foot
    } | xsltproc - "$@"
}
```

It seems to work fine if I provide real files as arguments to xsltproc.  In the case where I call it with a process substitution on the other hand:

```
$ quickxsl <(cat xml/kconf.xml) <<QUICKXSL
QUICKXSL
warning: failed to load external entity "/dev/fd/63"
unable to parse /dev/fd/63
```

Now, I understand that the pipe path is being provided to a sub process connected via another pipe (xsltproc).  So I rewrote it slightly:

```
function quickxsl() {
    xsltproc - "$@" < <( _quickxsl head && cat && _quickxsl foot )
}
```

It seemed to resolve things a little

```
/dev/fd/63:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
/dev/fd/63:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
unable to parse /dev/fd/63
```

Any idea why the pipe cannot be inherited?

Update:

If I simplify the quickxsl function again:

```
function quickxsl() {
    xsltproc <( _quickxsl head && cat && _quickxsl foot ) "$@"
}
```

I get the same issue, but it's easy to identify which fifo is causing the issue with a bit of xtrace...

```
$ quickxsl <(cat xml/kconf.xml) <<QUICKXSL
QUICKXSL
+ quickxsl /dev/fd/63
++ cat xml/kconf.xml
+ xsltproc /dev/fd/62 /dev/fd/63
++ _quickxsl head
++ [[ head == \h\e\a\d ]]
++ cat
++ cat -
++ _quickxsl foot
++ [[ foot == \h\e\a\d ]]
++ cat
/dev/fd/62:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
/dev/fd/62:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
cannot parse /dev/fd/62
```

The purpose of this exercise is to have the 'process substitution' pipe, connected to a function that returns XML on it's standard output, which it does and works correctly.  If I write the contents to a file and pass that to the function, all is well.  If I use process substitution, the child process can't read from the pipe and the pipe appears closed or inaccessible.  Example:

```
quickxsl <(my_soap_service "query") <<XSL
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/some/path/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
XSL
```

As you can see, it provides some shortcuts.

Update:

A good point was that pipes can't be continuously opened or closed.  Strace output for xsltproc reveals it only opens the file once.

```
$ grep /dev/fd !$
grep /dev/fd /tmp/xsltproc.strace
execve("/usr/bin/xsltproc", ["xsltproc", "/dev/fd/62"], [/* 31 vars */]) = 0
stat("/dev/fd/62", {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/fd/62", {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/fd/62", {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/dev/fd/62", O_RDONLY)            = 3
write(2, "/dev/fd/62:1: ", 14)          = 14
write(2, "/dev/fd/62:1: ", 14)          = 14
write(2, "cannot parse /dev/fd/62\n", 24) = 24
```

Blimey, I overlooked seeking:

```
read(3, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UT"..., 16384) = 390
read(3, "", 12288)                      = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
lseek(3, 18446744073709547520, SEEK_SET) = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
```

Comment: What is the question?!

Comment: Sorry about that, when I hit enter it posted the question instead of inserting a new line.

Comment: You're never using fifos, let alone named ones. You're using process substitution and HERE-documents

Comment: Okay. I've updated the question.  Presumably you know the answer?

Comment: Replace `xsltproc` with `strace -o xsltproc.strace xsltproc`, and then look at the log file (`xsltproc.strace`) to see if `xsltproc` opens and closes the file multiple times.  If it does, then it is incompatible with devices like pipes and FIFOs (and terminals) which cannot be read multiple times.  You might need to modify the command line a bit to get a process name embedded in the logging file name.

Comment: Good call, but already been there.  But just for your enjoyment, I'll include it in the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Something I overlooked before was seeks.  Looks like you were right, xsltproc expects to be able to navigate the file.  Doesn't explain how it can accept '-' as a file argument though.

Comment: It may be the case that it special-cases the argument `-` (avoiding seeks in that case), but assumes that *any* other named input can be seeked on.

Comment: Shame it doesn't seek based on type.  It stats the file several times, so it knows it is a fifo.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I found a bug in xsltproc.  It doesn't recognise FIFO file types and tries to seek on the FIFO file descriptor after reading in the document.  I have raised a bug.  A work-around is to parse the xsltproc arguments for FIFO file types and convert them into temporary files that can be seeked by xsltproc.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730545